# Word for articles grouped in a Series, but not initially intended to be a part of any series

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word to describe a particular grouping of individual articles within a specific topic.

The context for this word is I have a blog, and on the blog I have a bunch of articles. A large part of the articles were written as a part of an explicit series. Which is to say: one article follows another, there is a definite order the reader is supposed to read through them, and later articles use knowledge shared in the earlier articles.

But I also have a bunch of other, stand-alone articles, which aren't explicitly tied to other articles in any other series, that all share some commonalities. I want to refer to these groupings of articles as *something* -- and that is the word I am looking for.

Example sentence:

> The following are links to **meta-series**: Articles which weren't initially written as a part of a series, but whose concepts overlap enough that grouping them together is helpful to the reader.

So far, I've tried **Meta-Series**, but I feel that means something more like a series of series, not necessarily a set of individual independent articles grouped together within an informal series.

The new grouping may have a suggested order the articles should be read in, so simply calling them a "group" or "topic" or "compendium" or some such doesn't quite work.

A single word or compound word is ideal. I'm also willing to consider a phrase if one fits the description above well.

Comment: random series of articles. \\"meta" means about the word that follows it. meta language, language used to talk about language.

Comment: @Lambie Random isn't necessarily the right word, as it indicates the articles within the grouping weren't curated but picked... well, at random.  BUT, thanks for confirming my suspicions that *meta* is definitely the wrong word =)

Comment: Your own term "stand-alone articles" works.

Comment: @Lawrence Individually, yes, that is what they are called. But I'm looking for a term to label a new construct, which is a collection of those stand-alone articles.

Comment: These are ***Related*** articles

Comment: “Articles tagged [subject]” is one way to say it

Comment: Bunch of articles? Are they about flowers? Some basics to attend to first, I think.

Comment: @Jim The articles *within* the grouping will be related to one another. But I'm looking for a name of the grouping itself.

Comment: @David The blog is linked from my profile if you want to see it. It covers various Network Engineering topics. And a lot of the individual articles all correspond to a particular a bigger "category" of topics within Network Engineering.  Is that enough details or was there something else I could provide / answer with?

Comment: Just call it  ***"On the Topic Of ..."***  Inside that is the list of topics and inside these are the related articles

Comment: You can abuse the technical term *sideband* as a kind of pun on *sidebar*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Went with **Index**. Thank you everyone for your help.

> The following are links to **Indexes**: Lists of articles which weren’t initially written as a part of a series, but who’s concepts overlap enough that grouping them together is helpful to the reader.